# Laravel Backpack: coordinates field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a field named `map_box` which contains coordinates (see the example below) and cannot be serve as string.

Previously, before Backpack, I use to cast the field to an array `'map_box' => 'array'` and the result was the following: *note that the coordinates are not string*

```
[
    -73.661,
    45.589
],
```

Now, I am trying to achieve the same result, but I keep getting an array of strings. I have tried using the `repeatable` field with `numbers` field in it, but the numbers are string. I have also tried to cast the field, then use the `text` field but this returns an error (as the form is expecting a string and not an array).

My goal is to be able to edit this field in a CRUD controller while being able to serve them with the correct format in my API. Any ideas on how I could achieve the same result as above? I can also use the following format, if this one is possible:

```
{
   lon: -73.661,
   lat: 45.589
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if i understand you correctly ... what backpack has to do with this casting?

however if you have something like:

```
$value='"max_box":{lon: -73.661, lat: 45.589}';
```

or any string and you want to get float number positive or negative you can use this:

```
 preg_match_all('/-?\d+\.\d+/', $value, $matches);
```

the $matches[0] will be an array of your numbers

Comment: No, I want to edit this field in the backend CRUD controller. I have made change to my question to make it more clear. I really need to stick with the format because of how my api is handled.

Comment: what is the column type of this field?

Comment: it's a string, but I can change it if needed

Comment: it should be json, so  repeatable could deal with it

Comment: even with JSON, I still have the problem that the coordinates are saved as string and not float `{"lat": "45.589", "lon": "-82.661"}` instead of `{"lat": 45.589, "lon": -73.661}`